# Calling Controller.Redirect or Controller.RedirectToAction from an external library

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Environment: ASP.NET MVC 4, Visual Studio 2012

The AccountController created by the MVC 4 template includes a RedirectToLocal routine, which prevents URL spoofing attacks.  I want to move this routine to my own external library (in its own library dll project).  After some investigation, it looks like the best way to do this is to extend the Controller class.  My (unsuccessful) attempt to do so is shown below.

My problem is that Controller.Redirect and Controller.RedirectToAction are both protected internal functions, and are "inaccessible due to their protection level".

What is the usual way of calling Redirect or RedirectToAction from an external library?

```
public static class ControllerExtensionMethods
{
    public static ActionResult RedirectToLocal(
                                  this Controller controller,
                                  string redirectUrl)
        {
            if (controller.Url.IsLocalUrl(redirectUrl)) {
                return controller.Redirect(redirectUrl);  // error
            } else {
                return controller.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); // error
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess one way to solve this is to fabricate and return a new ActionResult rather than trying to call the protected Redirect routines.  I would appreciate confirmation from someone who knows this stuff better than I.

```
public static class ControllerExtensionMethods
{
    public static ActionResult RedirectToLocal(
                                  this Controller controller,
                                  string redirectUrl)
        {
            if (controller.Url.IsLocalUrl(redirectUrl)) {
                return new RedirectResult(redirectUrl);
            } else {
                return new RedirectToRouteResult(
                   new RouteValueDictionary {
                       {"controller", controllerName},
                       {"action", actionName}
                   });
            }
        }
}
```